# FAKE get TeamCity build branch

Tags: f#, teamcity, f#-fake

I'm constructing some build scripts using FAKE for a TeamCity setup. Part of my build requires me to access the `teamcity.build.branch` parameter, however because it's not an environment variable, I'm not sure how to access it.

I've tried adding `%teamcity.build.branch%` to an environment variable in TeamCity but it doesn't seem to like that. I also can't access it using the FAKE git module because team city agents don't use git to get the project files, TeamCity hands it to them.

How would I go about getting the `teamcity.build.branch` parameter through to my FAKE scripts? Ideally I'd like it as an environment variable so I can pick it up straight from within the script, but I'm open to any other ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out with a bit of help from @Nadeem's answer.

I now have my build.bat/cmd file taking in a parameter which I'm then passing into my Fake.exe call like so:

`"packages\FAKE\tools\Fake.exe" build.fsx branch=%1`

Then inside my FAKE code I'm using the `getBuildParamOrDefault "branch" <default branch here>`.

I'm then using this as the branch name. I'm also using a string split on the build param that comes in because normally it's in the format of `ref/head/<branch name>` and I only want the branch name.

I also had to pass in `%teamcity.build.vcs.branch.<project>%` instead of `%teamcity.build.branch%` as my agents didn't like the implicit requirement. I'm not entire sure why this is but all is working well now.

Answer (score 1):

Try passing `%teamcity.build.branch%` as a parameter in your build step.

Comment: I've figured it out now and posted my answer with credit to yours. Thanks!